# Why my DC thick charging cable is slower than a thinner one? (having same power rating & adaptor)

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, electric-current, electronics, electrical-engineering

Does that means thick wire cause more current loss than thinner one?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thicker cable will have *less* power loss because its resistance will be less than that of the thinner cable. If there really is a difference between the charging rates it means there's something suspicious going on here.  I suggest you do an experiment with the battery in your device discharged to exactly the same extent and then time the charging with the two different cables, and report the results here so we can study them.